# broccoli-closure-compiler install error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to test  [es-6 promise-polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise), for the testing one the node packages requried is `broccoli-closure-compiler`, which is not getting installed, I am behind a proxy server, is that the problem, but i have proxy config for both git and npm, so they are working fine, for more info, please refer to the screenshot of the command prompt,

[image]

edit:

the text in screenshot

D:\pt>npm install broccoli-closure-compiler
npm WARN package.json jshint@0.9.1 No repository field.
\

> closurecompiler@1.3.2 install D:\pt\node_modules\broccoli-closure-compiler\node_modules\closurecompiler
>   npm run-script configure

\

> closurecompiler@1.3.2 configure D:\pt\node_modules\broccoli-closure-compiler\node_modules\closurecompiler
>   node scripts/configure.js

Configuring ClosureCompiler.js 1.3.2 ...

Downloading http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.tar.gz ...
  ? Download failed: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

? Unfortunately, ClosureCompiler.js could not be configured.
    See: https://github.com/dcodeIO/ClosureCompiler.js (create an issue maybe)

Answer (score 0):

what I am suggesting is not a solution, these are mere work-around( aka really bad hacks)

if you are facing this, it is because you are behind a proxy server and one of the scripts trying to install clousurecompiler does not have the proxy settings set.

work around one : well, find a way to connect without proxy server, or install in a machine outside proxy server, copy the node_module files to your system,

work around 2 (the one I used) :

1. when you look at the screenshot, you would notice that at one point "node scripts/configure.js" is run, this is the crucial point, find a way to pause the processing just before this point,
2. open the 'configure.js' file, it would be at '.\node_modules\broccoli-closure-compiler\node_modules\closurecompiler\scripts' in node project directory,
3. comment line 65 in that i.e `fail();` to `//fail();`
4. continue the installation process,
5. manually download  http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.tar.gz , put the extracted file at '.\node_modules\broccoli-closure-compiler\node_modules\closurecompiler\compiler' in your project directory

(... told you this is a bad solution )